# creating singular resources in jsonapi-resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, singleton, jsonapi-resources

Using the jsonapi-resources gem (and Rails 4), I'm attempting to create a singular (or singleton) resource (not supplying the id on the url for the standard show, update and delete requests), in my case for a profile of the current (logged in) user, so I can do a 'GET /profiles' rather than a 'GET /profiles/:id'.

I've added the singular route to the config/routes.rb file:

jsonapi_resource :profiles

as per the documents https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources#jsonapi_resource

So how do I modify the resource (ProfileResource) to map the id to the current_user (via the context)?

the existing demo apps do not demonstrate using the singular resource, and there doesn't seemed to be any documentation that (explicitly) address this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Profile resource, you can override the `self.find_by_key` method to instantiate via the user stored in the context, if the key is 'me'.
For current user, you could hit `/profiles/me`.

```
def self.find_by_key(key, options = {})
  new(options[:context][:current_user], options[:context]) if key == 'me'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

That works! (thks)

the key for me was

config/routes.rb

```
jsonapi_resource :profile
```

and in the app/resources/profile_resource.rb

```
def self.find_by_key(key, options = {})
  model = options[:context][:current_user]
  fail JSONAPI::Exceptions::RecordNotFound.new(key) if model.nil?
  new(model, options[:context])
end
```

and then hitting(GET,PUT,POST,DELETE) '/profile' works fine.